# Rails, Capybara.using_session(...), visiting a page, and having ruby-debug causes rspec suite seem to hang after run even though all specs passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, ruby-debug

**Rails** 7.0.4

**Rspec** 3.11.0

**Capybara** 3.37.1

**selenium-webdriver (gem) 4.5.0**

**with Ruby-debug (`gem 'debug', platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]`) in Gemfile**

whenever I try to add `Capybara.using_session` call, my suite hangs.
it hangs after it completes all the specs, even when passing.

my driver is set to :

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

but I noticed it happens if I change the driver to `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome` also

here's the spec that reproduces it:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "client app", type: :feature  do
  describe "when starting the experience", type: :feature do
    # TODO: figure out why capy is hanging here

    it "can load the home page" do
      # THIS CAUSES AFTER-RSPEC HANG even though all specs pass
      Capybara.using_session("client session") do
        visit "/"
      end
    end

    it "loads with a client id" do
      visit '/'
    end
  end
end
```

I have isolated it to ***these THREE*** conditions :

1. using Capybara.using_session and visiting a page using `visit` inside the using_session block (if I remove either the visit or the using_session, it works)
2. In another test in the same suite, visiting any other page using `visit` (if I remove the `visit` call in the other spec, it works)
3. the `debug` gem (ruby-debug) (if I remove `gem 'debug', platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]` from the Gemfile)

***This is a very strange bug.***

Capy hang looks like:
[image]

my `spec/rails_helper.rb` file is

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'

require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

IMPORTANT: Although I have isolated it this far, I am strangely unable to isolate it any further or even able to reproduce it in a new Rails app, even though this Rails app is just a month old.

Here, I have taken the app where it is broken and ***removed everything else*** (really, I removed EVERYTHING and the hang still happens).

I have compared the remaining code carefully to a newly generated app and bizarrely I cannot reproduce the same bug (Using the exact same spec and setup) in a new app, so it must involve a 4th unknown variable I cannot see yet.

## REPRODUCTION

Bare-bones reproduction app here:
https://github.com/jasonfb/StrangeCapybaraHang

This app was created as a FORK of my app, then I removed everything non-essential. Notice that it contains almost nothing, and only 1 spec.

When I run rspec on this app (broken), see "DEBUGGER: Attaching after process 77726 fork to child process 77733" AND the suite hangs after it runs
[image]

Here, on this 2nd attempt to recreate the problem, I tried to go *forward* to create the bug: https://github.com/jasonfb/StrangeCapyHangForward

I setup a new Rails app and then attempted to recreate all of the conditions explained above to produce the bug... BUT... ***I can't reproduce the bug in this new app!!***

So that means even though I've identified the 3 elements of the bug, there MUST be a 4th element I am not seeing yet.

Notice that in this app, it has same exact spec (see spec/system/test_capy_hand_spec.rb), the same exact rails_helper file, the same exact Gems, etc as the other repo where the bug manifests.

However, on this app, I never see "DEBUGGER: Attaching after process 77726 fork to child process...." even when `debug` Gem is in the Gemfile. **Why is that?**

I *also* DO NOT see the hang.

[image]

## 2022-12-15 SOLVED!

Comment: Please, provide your configuration too... it will be almost impossible to debug this issue without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: Please show the full test you’re using ‘using_session’ in

Comment: @ThomasWalpole — updated with my full spec file. thanks for your help! I isolated it to using `Capybara.using_session` along with any other test. Both tests must call visit. Working in reproduction app again now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

The issue is in the `selenium-webdriver` gem. Upgrade from 4.5.0 in your StrangeCapybaraHang project to 4.7.1 and it should solve your problem immediately.

### Reproducing from Scratch

1. Fork the [StrangeCapyHangForward](https://github.com/jasonfb/StrangeCapyHangForward) repo.
2. Run `./bin/setup && yarn build`. Note, if esbuild is not globally installed, you'll need to add it with `yarn add esbuild` since it's missing from package.json.
3. Downgrade the `selenium-webdriver` gem to the same version that is in [StrangeCapybaraHang](https://github.com/jasonfb/StrangeCapybaraHang). For example, in your Gemfile's `:test` group: `gem 'selenium-webdriver', '4.5.0'`
4. `bundle install && rspec`. It hangs.

#### Example of Gemfile with not working `selenium-webdriver` gem added

```
# Gemfile of StrangeCapyHangForward
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debug', platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # add the older version of the gem
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '4.5.0'
end
```

### Steps to Fix

1. Add `gem 'selenium-webdriver', '4.7.1'` to your Gemfile in [StrangeCapyHangForward](https://github.com/jasonfb/StrangeCapyHangForward).
2. `bundle install`
3. Run `rspec`. No more hang!

Note: You may have to grep and kill existing rspec processes. For example:

```bash
ps -ax | grep rspec
# take process ids for all the above and run (substituting 71529 for your pids): 
kill -9 71529
```

#### Example Gemfile  with working `selenium-webdriver` gem added

```rb
# Example Gemfile with working version of selenium-webdriver
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debug', platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # add selenium-webdrive gem coded to 4.7.1
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '4.7.1'
end
```

I believe the issue is related to concurrency and rspec not properly `kill`ing all the test processes, although this is difficult to confirm. We had big trouble with our test suite and concurrency, too, until we forcibly upgraded many of our gems (including dependencies).

For example, before upgrading run `rspec` a few times and grep your processes: `ps -ax | grep rspec`. You'll see lots of existing ones there. I did check the [selenium-webdrive changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/rb/CHANGES) to see if there was anything obvious that would cause this, but I didn't see anything.

Anyways, hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: yes, this is correct! Upgrading from selenium-webdriver 4.5.0 to 4.7.1 eliminates the issue and was indeed the 4th variable. Thank you so much!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help, @JasonFB. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score -4):

Try removing the debug gem, as it is probably causing the issue with capybara.

Comment: Yes that fixes it, but why?

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.  @yellowcrayon.